# Matlab regex: replace comma and one letter

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have a string like this in matlab.

```
str='42 21 S'
```

How could I convert it into the following form?

```
str='42.21'
```

What I tried with `regexprep()` is the following:

```
regexprep(str,'S','');
regexprep(str,' ', '.')
```

which leaves me with this

```
str='42.21.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do the trick, Matlab is not great with strings though so there's likely to be all sorts of ways to do it, not just using `regexp`/`regexprep`:

```
regexprep(regexp('42 21 A','\d+\s\d+','match'),'\s','.')
```

The `regexp` removes the space and the `S` at the end, and then the `regexprep` replaces the space with a period.

Answer (score 1):

For simple replacements you don't have to use [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html). You can use the much simpler [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html):

```
str = strrep(str, ' S', '');
str = strrep(str, ' ', '.');
```

If you require more general replacement rules, you should use `regexprep`, like David's answer for example.